# Почему не запускается бот, собранный в pyinstaller

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

Я написал юзербота, который управляет мои телеграмм-аккаунтом и хочу его отправить человеку. Вот примерный код:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.types import Message

spam_channel_ids = [-1001977372098, -1001458702882, -1001558435116, -1001653700348, -1001278646951]
spam_text = 'Текст'
manage_channel_id = -1001977372098
interval = 20

client = Client(name='me_client', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)
scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()


async def sendMessages():
    global spam_channel_ids
    for channel in spam_channel_ids:
        await client.send_message(channel, spam_text)


@client.on_message()
async def handleCommands(client: Client, message: Message):
#work

scheduler.start()
client.run()
```

Теперь, когда я собрал этот скрипт на Linux, нажимаю на exe файл, а он не открывается, что я могу с этим сделать? Инпут пробовал писать вконце, смысла нет.

Comment: Что пишет? EXE файл открываете через вино? Вы уверены, что все-таки расширение не Py?

Comment: Ну как бы да, exe без дополнительных ухищрений (типа wine) на Linux запустить не получится.

Comment: В общем, нужно через pyinstaller создавать исполняемый файл для Linux, для этого запускать сборку нужно на Linux (ну или в WSL)

Comment: я это делаю на Linux Mint, что мне нужно сделать, чтобы все заработало?

Comment: Запускать pyinstaller там же.